# siunitx with fourier result in no more \micro prefix

Tags: siunitx, fourier

```
\documentclass[french]{article}

    \RequirePackage{fourier}
    \RequirePackage{fontspec} 

\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{%
    unit-mode = text,%
    locale=FR,%
    detect-all,% Problème avec euro, utiliser \text{€} en mode math
    inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{{}\cdot{}},%
    group-minimum-digits=4,
    text-angstrom={Å},math-angstrom={\text{Å}}
}

\begin{document}
\SI{60}{\micro\s}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\othermu` for the upright mu. The problem is that `fourier` uses its own math font encodings.

```
\documentclass[french]{article}

\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\setmainfont{erewhon}

\sisetup{
    unit-mode = text,
    locale=FR,
    detect-all,% Problème avec euro, utiliser \text{€} en mode math
    inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{{}\cdot{}},
    group-minimum-digits=4,
    text-angstrom={Å},math-angstrom={\text{Å}},
    text-micro=\ensuremath{\othermu},
    math-micro=\othermu,
}

\begin{document}
\SI{60}{\micro\s}
\end{document}
```

[image]